# How to convert image to uint8list in flutter without using async?

Tags: image, pdf, image-processing, flutter, flutter-layout

PdfImage requires **Uint8List** as param but I have **ImageProvider**. So how can we convert image to uint8list in flutter?

```
var imageProvider = AssetImage('assets/test.jpg');

final image = PdfImage(
  pdf.document,
  image:???, /// Uint8List required
  width: img.width,
  height: img.height,
);
```

**Using FutureBuilder:**
[image]

Comment: simply use `rootBundle.load()`, as it returns a `Future` you have to use `then` method after `load` completes

Comment: Your answer is correct in normal case. But in my case it little bit different. I Have to render image in pdf. So, I need to work without async func in stateless widget

Comment: where did i say `async`? i said: use `then` method

Comment: I have to use this in build function that return the stateless widget. So, how to do this?

Comment: Nope unable to use it when using the packages: 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' as fw; and 'package:pdf/widgets.dart'

Comment: @pskink Please check the about screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197202/discussion-between-jazzbpn-and-pskink).

Comment: I have to use this package: import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw; ERROR: The function 'FutureBuilder' isn't defined. 

Note: I think the FutureBuilder may not till build in the pdf-package.

Comment: I can't use the material package because I am working on dart_pdf library.

Comment: ok, first of all, what do you want to use with `PdfImage`? what do you need it for? what does it have to do with your custom `StatelessWidget`? is it used by its `build()` method? - if you just want to save your pdf file then do not mix pdf widgets and flutter widgets

Comment: First, I want to split the child widget to smaller ones. Reason, the child widget container contains the dynamic image list that has to render in pdf. 

Note: I had already chat with the package builder of dart_pdf. He mentioned it is not possible to create the image without using async.

Comment: Child widget container contains the dynamic image list that has to render in pdf. I just want to render the image in pdf and download. Sorry, If I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 12):

Use `rootBundle.load()`

```
(await rootBundle.load(/*YOUR IMAGE PATH HERE*/)).buffer.asUint8List()
```

---

#### UPDATE

As `load()` is an async operation, you need to wait until the data is fully loaded. Try substituting the UI with some loading indicator until then.

```
ByteData imageData;

@override
void initState() {
  rootBundle.load('assets/test.jpg')
    .then((data) => setState(() => this.imageData = data));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (imageData == null) {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }

  final image = PdfImage(
    pdf.document,
    image: imageData.buffer.asUint8List(),
    width: img.width,
    height: img.height,
  );

  ...
}
```

Comment: The await expression can only be used in an asynchronous function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*' ??

Comment: Is is possible to convert without async call?

Comment: Your answer is correct in normal case. But in my case it little bit different. I Have to render image in pdf. So, I need to work without async func in stateless widget.

Comment: Sorry this is the only way I know

Comment: Used packages: 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' as fw;
 and 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';

Answer (score 4):

I tried different solutions to convert image to UInt8List and finally found one Solution. It worked for me.

```
XFile? image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
     source: ImageSource.gallery,
); // Upload file from gallery

final bytes = await image!.readAsBytes(); // Converts the file to UInt8List
```

for the output, i used MemoryImage

```
MemoryImage(bytes!);
```

Answer (score 2):

in Flutter, attaching local image to pdf file.
Actually It's a simple solution to add our local image to pdf file. 
just copy paste the following code and try

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/logo.jpg');
final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

final image = PdfImage.file(
  pdf.document,
  bytes: list,
);

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(build: (pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(image),
  ); // Center
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split initState into two if you prefer:

```
@override
void initState() {
  loadAsset('test.jpg');
}

void loadAsset(string name) async {
  var data = await rootBundle.load('assets/$name');
  setState(() => this.imageData = data);
}
```

Note that this will cause build() to run an extra time but I find it easier on the eye. With Michael's circular Indicator, this is a harmless extra cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: "*You can't*".

But [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_converter) contains all possible image converters with `sync` and `async`. Code example with `sync`:

```
final r = source.widgetImageSync;
// or
... = source.uiImageSync;
... = source.uint8ListSync;
... = source.imageProviderSync;
```