# Flutter imagePicker to Uint8list

Tags: list, flutter

so I want to Store my Image to List but I cant convert it to Uint8list
is there a way in flutter I can use another option such as RootBundle ???

why dnt use RootBundler ??
the problem is RootBundle need declaration on Pubspec.yaml under Asset section
but the the Image I want to convert is on App temp directory something I cant change
so RootBundle cant access and always throw Asset is null ( which is not ) because its not declarated in pubspec.yaml

```
static Future pickImage(PickType type) async {
    try {
      var photo = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source:
            type == PickType.Camera ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 80,
      );
      var photosPicked;
      print(photo!.name);
      Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      print(tempDir.path);
      rootBundle
          .load('${tempDir.path}/${photo.name}')
          .then((value) => photosPicked = value);
      return photosPicked;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert image to uint8list in flutter without using async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264397/how-to-convert-image-to-uint8list-in-flutter-without-using-async)

Comment: no, rootBundle can only access that if theyre local asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by Using ReadAsByte function

```
static Future pickImage(PickType type) async {
    try {
      var photo = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source:
            type == PickType.Camera ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 80,
      );

      File imageFile = File(photo!.path);
      Uint8List imageRaw = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
      return imageRaw;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```